# How to use `git stash --patch` together with `git stash save`

Tags: git, git-stash

I want to use:

```
git stash save "Message describing stash"
```

…but I also want to stash only *some* of my working directory, using:

```
git stash --patch
```

How can I create a stash that both **has a message**, *and* **includes only selected changes**?

Answer (score -1):

Simply combine the two commands together like so:

```
git stash save --patch "Message describing stash"
```

This will produce the desired behavior of creating a stash using the hunk-staging interface that also has a message visible in `git stash list`.

---

*(Figured this out by just trying it, and in retrospect it feels pretty obvious. Still, something about it was non-obvious enough to cause me to look it up, so I'm leaving this here for anyone else in the same boat.*  *I think maybe seeing `save` as a subcommand of `stash` rather than an option (like `--save`) may have been what threw me off—I'd likely guess that a hypothetical `--save` option could be combined with `--patch`, but implicitly I think seeing `save` without hyphens led me to a question like, "does the `--patch` option also work with the the `save` subcommand?" And… I seem to have a quick impulse to check with the internet before trying something new in `git`.* *)*